# Unity3D Window editor save image component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to ask how to save image(texture) component for later work even when program is restarted.

[image]

Because now when I exit program and restart it image component is missing.

Is there any possible way to save image component?

Comment: You need to mark your class with the `[System.Serializable]` attribute. Unity serializes the editor windows when you save the project/scene, but if it is unmarked it will not persist.

Comment: @BrandonMiller i believe the component is already serialized as the fields wouldn’t appear as drag-n-drop otherwise?

Comment: No, as long as the fields are public it will show in the editor window.

Comment: hmm.. well yes but simple types and many unity components (i.e mono behaviors) are automatically serialized thus marking them public will expose them. but if you don’t mark a custom class as serializable then marking a reference of a custom class as public won’t do anything. also as you probably already know, you don’t need to denote a field as public to expose it, you can simply mark it with the serialized field attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you assign the inspector reference to a prefab in you’re hierarchy you need to also hit ‘apply’ so that any changes are saved. if it’s not a prefab then the state should be saved anyway.